# When I click on an internal link in the drop-down menu, the entire menu closes and it will not let me select the internal link

Tags: php, laravel, responsive, megamenu

I am working on making a mega menu with categories responsive.  The site is using Laravel, PHP and a bootstrap framework.  I did not write the original code, but as I have made the menu responsive, I have come into an issue.

When I click on the hamburger, it opens the menu.  When I click on any internal link, or anywhere on the entire screen, the menu closes.  I have tried the "stop propagation on numerous elements with no success.  Since this is a custom build where the categories are also used on internal searches, I am not sure how to fix.  I did remove the entire menu and put in a static one and everything seemed to work well.

```html
<div class="navbar-buttons">
    <div class="login">
        <a href="{{ route('vendor-sign-up') }}" style="margin: 5px">Vendor</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="session_check('register-modal')" style="margin: 5px">Sign Up</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="session_check('login-modal')" class="login-link" style="margin: 5px">Log In</a>
    </div>
</div>
@else
<div class="navbar-dropdown">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn account-options dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="color: #240462 !important">
            <img
                src="{{ Auth::user()->provider ? asset('images/avatar/' . Auth::user()->avatar) : asset('storage/' . Auth::user()->avatar) }}"
                alt="" style="width: 24px; height: 24px">&nbsp;
            {{ Auth::user()->first_name }}
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            @if (Auth::user()->role->name == 'owner' || Auth::user()->role->name == 'author')
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('vendor-dashboard') }}"><i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i> My
                Business</a>
            @elseif (Auth::user()->role->name == 'superadmin' || Auth::user()->role->name == 'admin')
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('admin-dashboard') }}"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i> Admin
                Dashboard</a>
            @endif
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> My Profile</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-star"></i> My Reviews</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('search-favorites') }}?mapView=1"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i> My
                Favorites</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item logout" href="#"><i class="fas fa-sign-out"></i> Logout</a>
            <form name="logoutForm" action="/logout" method="POST">{{ csrf_field() }}</form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endif
</div>
</nav>
<a href="" class="ic menu category-dropdown-menu ">
    <span class="line"></span>
    <span class="line"></span>
    <span class="line"></span>
</a>
<a href="" class="ic close d-none"></a>
<div class="category-nav container-fluid">
    <div class="container position-relative">
        @foreach (\App\PrimaryCategory::orderBy('name')->get() as $primary)
        <div class="category-dropdown" data-id="{{ $primary->id }}">
            <div class="category-dropdown-title">{{ $primary->name }}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="category-dropdown-menu" data-id="{{ $primary->id }}">
            <div class="row">
                <?php $last = 0; $cols = 1; ?>
                <div class="col-3">
                    @foreach ($primary->secondary_categories->sortBy('name')->sortBy('menu_sequence') as $secondary)
                    <?php 
if ($secondary->menu_display_tertiaries)
$cur = 3 + count($secondary->tertiary_categories);
else
$cur = 3;
?>
                    @if ($last + $cur > 26)
                    <?php $last = 0; $cols++ ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    @endif
                    <div class="category-secondary">
                        <div class="category-secondary-title">
                            <a href="/listings?pc={{ $primary->id }}&sc={{ $secondary->id }}">{{ $secondary->name }}
                                &raquo;</a>
                            @if ($secondary->menu_display_tertiaries)
                            <hr>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                        @if ($secondary->menu_display_tertiaries)
                        <div class="category-secondary-menu">
                            @foreach ($secondary->tertiary_categories->sortBy('name')->sortBy('menu_sequence') as
                            $tertiary)
                            @if ($tertiary->menu_display)
                            <a
                                href="/listings?pc={{ $primary->id }}&sc={{ $secondary->id }}&tc={{ $tertiary->id }}">{{ $tertiary->name }}</a><br>
                            @endif
                            @endforeach
                        </div>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                    <?php $last += $cur ?>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
                @for ($i = 0; $i < (3 - $cols); $i++) <div class="col-3">
            </div>
            @endfor
            <div class="dropdown-image">
                <img src="{{ asset('/images/category/category2.png') }}" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
    @if (!Auth::guest())
    @if (!isset($favorites))
    <div class="search-favorites">
        <a href="{{ route('search-favorites') }}?mapView=1" title="Favorites"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></a>
    </div>
    @else
    <div class="undo-favorites">
        <a href="{{ route('listings') }}" title="Return to Search"><i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i></a>
    </div>
    @endif
    @else
    <div class="search-favorites favorites-guest" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#favorites-modal">
        <a href="#" title="Favorites"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></a>
    </div>
    @endif
</div>
</div>



<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.js') }}"></script>


<script>
    $('input[name="q"]').focus(function () {
        $(this).parent().find('.input-group-prepend').addClass('d-none');
        $(this).css('border-left', '1px solid #ced4da');
        $(this).css('border-top-left-radius', '.25rem');
        $(this).css('border-bottom-left-radius', '.25rem');
        $(this).css('padding-left', '10px');
    });

    $('input[name="q"]').focusout(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).parent().find('.input-group-prepend').removeClass('d-none');
            $(this).css('border-left', 'none');
            $(this).css('border-top-left-radius', '0');
            $(this).css('border-bottom-left-radius', '0');
            $(this).css('padding-left', '0');
        }
    });

    @if(isset($_GET['login-modal']))
    $('#login-modal').modal({
        backdrop: 'static',
    });
    @elseif(isset($_GET['register-modal']))
    $('#register-modal').modal({
        backdrop: 'static',
    });
    @endif

    function session_check(modal) {
        var url = "{{ route('session-check') }}";
        var options = {
            _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
        };
        $.post(url, options).done(function (data) {
            if (data.substr(0, 1) === '{') {
                $('#' + modal).modal({
                    backdrop: 'static',
                });
            } else {
                var current_url = '{!! Request::fullUrl() !!}';
                current_url = current_url.replace('?login-modal=1&', '?');
                current_url = current_url.replace('?login-modal=1', '');
                current_url = current_url.replace('&login-modal=1', '');
                current_url = current_url.replace('?register-modal=1&', '?');
                current_url = current_url.replace('?register-modal=1', '');
                current_url = current_url.replace('&register-modal=1', '');
                window.location = current_url + (current_url.match(/\?/) ? '&' : '?') + modal + '=1';
            }
        });
    }

    $('.login-with-email').click(function () {
        $('.first-wrap').addClass('d-none');
        $('.second-wrap').removeClass('d-none');
        $('.login-back').removeClass('d-none');
    });

    $('.login-back, .login-link').click(function () {
        $('.login-back').addClass('d-none');
        $('.first-wrap').removeClass('d-none');
        $('.second-wrap').addClass('d-none');
    });

    $('.logout').click(function () {
        $('form[name="logoutForm"]').submit();
    });



    $('.category-dropdown, .category-dropdown-menu').mouseover(function () {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        $('.category-dropdown-menu').each(function () {
            if ($(this).data('id') == id)
                $(this).removeClass('d-none');
        });
        $('.category-dropdown').each(function () {
            if ($(this).data('id') == id) {
                $(this).css('background', '#f0f0f0');
                $(this).css('border-left', '1px solid #ccc');
                $(this).css('border-right', '1px solid #ccc');
                $(this).css('border-bottom', 'none');
                $(this).css('padding-bottom', '1px');
            }
        });
    });

    $('.category-dropdown-menu').mouseleave(function () {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        $('.category-dropdown-menu').each(function () {
            if ($(this).data('id') == id)
                $(this).addClass('d-none');
        });
        $('.category-dropdown').each(function () {
            if ($(this).data('id') == id) {
                $(this).css('background', 'none');
                $(this).css('border-left', 'none');
                $(this).css('border-right', 'none');
                $(this).css('border-bottom', '1px solid #ccc');
                $(this).css('padding-bottom', '0');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('form[name="loginform"]').validate({
            rules: {
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 255,
                    email: true,
                },
                password: {
                    required: true,
                },
            },
            messages: {
                email: {
                    required: '* You must enter your email address to sign in.',
                    maxlength: '* This email address is too long [max 255 characters]',
                    email: '* This is not a valid email address.',
                },
                password: {
                    required: '* You must enter your password to sign in.',
                },
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                form.submit();
            }
        });

        $('form[name="registerform"]').validate({
            rules: {
                first_name: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 255,
                },
                last_name: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 255,
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 255,
                    email: true,
                    remote: {
                        url: "{{ route('verify-unique-email-no-invites') }}",
                        type: 'post',
                        data: {
                            _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}',
                            email: function () {
                                return $('#sign-up-email').val();
                            }
                        },
                    },
                },
                password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 6,
                },
                password_confirmation: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 6,
                    equalTo: '#sign-up-password',
                },
            },
            messages: {
                first_name: {
                    required: '* You must enter your first name to sign up.',
                    maxlength: '* This email address is too long [max 255 characters]',
                },
                last_name: {
                    required: '* You must enter your last name to sign up.',
                    maxlength: '* This email address is too long [max 255 characters]',
                },
                email: {
                    required: '* You must enter your email address to sign up.',
                    maxlength: '* This email address is too long [max 255 characters]',
                    email: '* This is not a valid email address.',
                    remote: '* This email is already in use.',
                },
                password: {
                    required: '* You must enter a password to sign up.',
                    minlength: '* Your password must be 6 characters or longer.',
                },
                password_confirmation: {
                    required: '* You must confirm your password to sign up.',
                    minlength: '* Your password must be 6 characters or longer.',
                    equalTo: '* Your passwords do not match.',
                },
            },
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                error.insertAfter(element.parent());
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                form.submit();
            }
        });

        $('form[name="loginform"] input').change(function () {
            $('form[name="loginform"]').valid();
        });

        $('form[name="registerform"] input').change(function () {
            $('form[name="registerform"]').valid();
        });

    });
</script>
@yield('scripts')
```